# Google Ads API - Does a REST API exist?

Tags: google-ads-api

Reference: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start

Quote (emphasis mine):

> The Google Ads API is the next generation of the AdWords API. It can
>   be accessed via gRPC and *JSON REST* from a variety of client
>   environments.

This would indicate a REST API exists.

However, I am unable to find any documentation for it, any endpoints - anything really.

Do they just mean they use that under the hood for the client libraries, or have I just not been able to find the right documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they have, let me explain

### They have two APIs,

One called `Google Adwords API` (old)
and another one is `Google Ads API` (new)

#### 1. Google Adwords API

***Note: Google AdWords API will sunset on April 27, 2022.***
So there is nothing to talk about this API because it will no more available

This API has only one interface: `gRPC`

Still, want to know more? docs link: [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start)

#### 2. Google Ads API

Ok this the stable API they have and it's amazing it's even a lot better than the older one!

This API has two interfaces: `gRPC` or `REST`

The docs to start: [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start)

Answer (score -1):

The REST API is really just for querying the discovery endpoints and getting meta data or testing the endpoints. It's explicitly not for reports or mutates. You need to use the client libraries (which are gRPC based, or build your own).

REST has a limit of 1000 requests per day which is tiny. gRPC is absolutely amazing. Just wrap your own rest methods around it (it's what I do) and you don't have to worry about the nitty gritty details. For example, if you're building /reports in your own app, tie the get method in whatever framework you're building to a custom gRPC request using the library.

Comment: Could you please mention the source of this info? I haven't seen anywhere in the official documentation where they say that REST and gRPC have different limits. And you say REST is not for mutates, but that doesn't seem to be true either (https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/common/mutate)